# [Laravel 8.x][Eloquent] Copying rows to another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL in the following format. I want to copy the entries in this table[products] to another table [user_products]. What is the best approach to do this?

In the user_products table while inserting the records, i will also have to add a user_id which gets passed to the code from a html form
[image]

Comment: On your query use `groupBy('event_id')`, that will filter duplicate id

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql trigger as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Here is the migration.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            ....
        });

        Schema::create('user_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            ....
        });

        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::unprepared('
        CREATE TRIGGER backup_users BEFORE INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO user_products(id,other_columns)
                values(new.id, new.other_columns);
            END
        ');
    }
```